# expo start stuck at starting metro

Tags: react-native, expo

I have tried everything from restarting computer, reinstalling node modules, checking network issues, but I cannot get the metro bundler to start.

These are my diagnostics, if anyone can help it would be much appreciated

```
 Expo CLI 5.0.1 environment info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 11.6.1
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 14.17.4 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.22.10 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.14.14 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 2021.12.20.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 2020.3 AI-203.7717.56.2031.7935034
      Xcode: /undefined - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      expo: ~44.0.0 => 44.0.0 
      react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1 
      react-dom: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1 
      react-native: 0.64.3 => 0.64.3 
      react-native-web: 0.17.1 => 0.17.1 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      expo-cli: 5.0.1
    Expo Workflow: managed
```

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/678469

This thread ended up being the right answer. Once I switched the command line location and booted up the ios simulator it also started working on my personal device.